# Avoid IndexOutOfRangeException by looping back to start of array

Tags: c#

I have a array [4,4] that I am looping through and printing values.

```
 trainingpatterns.array = new int[4, 4];
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
               var element1 = x + array.coordinates[0];

                var element2 = x + array.coordinates[2];

                var element3 = x + array.coordinates[4];

                var element4 = x + array.coordinates[6];

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)

            {
               var element1 = y + array.coordinates[1];

                var element2 = y + array.coordinates[3];

                var element3 = y + array.coordinates[5];

                var element4 = y + array.coordinates[7];





   Console.WriteLine(trainingpatterns.array[element2, element6]);
```

However my loop requires me to go over the index. So when it gets to [5,4] for example the exception will be thrown.

What I want to do is if the x value goes out of bounds, for it to loop back to the start. So for example [5,4] will print [0,4] or [6,4] will print [2,4].

I have tried using a try catch but I cannot make the function universal for all values.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to 'go over the index'?

Comment: What do you mean by "However my loop requires me to go over the index"? The code you've given doesn't...

Comment: You can use the mod operator `%` if you have an index that's going to grow larger than the bounds and you want it to wrap around.

Comment: @DStanley: Actually it'll stop at [3, 3] :)

Comment: @DStanley Actually it'll stop at `[3,3]`. But I think the OP is simply asking how to wrap array indices around. (And one answer is to index the array as `arr[i % 4]`.)

Comment: Aplogies, I am actually adding to the coordinates, which I have now added into my code. Which means I am producing coordinates that are larger than the array.

Comment: @user3365114: Right - in that case, use the code in my answer.

Comment: @DStanley Hello there, apologies, when you mean index the array as arr[i % 4], do you mean to add the mod operator when the array is being created?

Comment: @dvnrrs actually made that comment in response to my comment that was deleted (by me).

Comment: Oh yes sorry. @dvnrrs. Hello there, apologies, when you mean index the array as arr[i % 4], do you mean to add the mod operator when the array is being created?

Comment: @user3365114 No, when it's being accessed. `i % 4` will always be in the range [0, 3]; when `i` gets bigger it "wraps" around back to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you just want to use the `%` operator:

```
int length0 = inputArray.GetUpperBound(0);
int length1 = inputArray.GetUpperBound(1);
...

var value = inputArray[x % length0, y % length1];
```

Note that this will *not* wrap negative numbers, however - the range of `a % b` is `(-b, +b)`, whereas you want `[0, +b)`. Taking account of this is a bit more longwinded, but let me know if you need it. If your index values will always be non-negative, you don't need to worry about it.